# error funcion ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo este código en un archivo php:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<?php
    //Tabla inicial sin parámetros de búsqueda
    require('conexionbd.php');

    $general = 'SELECT * FROM pedidos';
    $result = mysql_query($general) or die('Consulta fallida: ' . mysql_error());

    echo "<table class='table table-striped table-pedidos-g'>\n";
    echo "<tr class='superior'>
            <td>Nº pedido</td>
            <td>Fecha</td>
            <td>Descuento</td>
            <td>Cliente</td>
            <td>Estado</td>
        </tr>";

    while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        echo "\t<tr>\n";
        foreach ($line as $col_value) {
            echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
        }
        echo "\t</tr>\n";
    }
    echo "</table>\n";

    // Liberar resultados
    mysql_free_result($result);

    // Cerrar la conexión
    mysql_close($link);
?>

<script>
    $('#buttonFechaPedido').click(function() {
        $('.table-pedidos-g').hide();
        $('.table-pedidos-n').hide();
        $('.table-pedidos-e').hide();
        var valorFecha = $('#inputFechaPedido').text();
        if (valorFecha.length == 0){
            $('#emptyFecha').removeClass('mistake');
        }
        else{
            $.ajax({
                data:  valorFecha,
                url:   'pedidos/pfechas.php',
                type:  'post',
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#tablaPedido").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
                },
                error:function (){
                    $('#errorFecha').removeClass('mistake');
                },
                success:  function (response) {
                    $("#tablaPedido").html(response);
                }
            });
        }       
    });
</script>
```

Y me esta generando el siguiente error en la consola: Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function

Comment: Ya intentaste con la versión minificada normal y no la slim?

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero no entiendo a que te refieres con version minificada normal y no la slim

Comment: Estás usando la versión slim.min.js trata usando la .min.js, la verdad no se que de diferente tenga la slim a la normal solo es una opinión

Answer (score 4):

La versión jQuery-slim no soporta Ajax: [documentación](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/)

Deberías usar: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js

Comment: Am vale, lo probaré asi. Gracias!!

Comment: no lo sabia que buena aldanux

Comment: me lo sospechaba incluso lo dije en los comentarios! Gracias por confirmar

Comment: Si tuviera la nota de la documentación donde lo dice será excelente. @CamiloVasquez es que esto suena a chino: *Ya intentaste con la versión minificada normal y no la slim*. Yo tampoco entendí :) Saludos.